# json data gives null reference exception after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, nullreferenceexception

I want to deserialize json data in asp.net c# code. I am receiving nullreference exception in the deserializing statement:

```
   public static string saveAllTreatments(string jsonval)
        {
            var output =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Treatments>(jsonval);
            Treatments tr = (Treatments)output;
            foreach (var item in tr.data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("date: {0}, number: {1}, name: {2}, note: {3}",item.date, item.number, item.name,item.note);
            }
}
```

here is my class:

```
public class Treatment
    {
        public DateTime date{ get; set; }
        public int number{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
    }
    public class Treatments {
        public List<Treatment> data { get; set; }

    }
```

and this is my json:

```
{"treatment":[{"date":"09.07.2015","number":"22","name":"Jackson","note":"bla"}]}
```

I see jsonval has json data (its not null has string json data), I receive null reference exception when deserializing to output. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the deserialization returned a null object. What is the JSON you tried to deserialize?

Comment: When asking about serialization/deserialization, is aways a good idea to show the content you are trying to deserialize (to see if it is correct, if it is a list or a single object, etc)

Comment: Please show the JSON you are trying to deserialize.  Perhaps your root container is not an array but an object?

Comment: The JSON key "treatment" does not agree with the member name Treatments.data.  Can you rename the member to "treatment" or change the JSON to use the key "data" so they do agree?

Comment: I tried it still returns null. Also i must take jsondata as a treatments list. like a treatments list and its objects (treatment).@JerryFederspiel

Comment: Is that json literally copied and pasted? There is a brace mismatch at the end- the closing square bracket and first curly brace are switched from what they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match your c# class to the JSON, you need to change the name of the `data` field to `treatment`:

```
public class Treatments
{
    public List<Treatment> treatment { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify the name with a [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
public class Treatments
{
    [JsonProperty("treatment")]
    public List<Treatment> data { get; set; }
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fBzYbT).

Comment: amazing, thank you! (your below answer with JsonProperty worked) :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want something more like this:

```
{
"treatment":{
            data:{
           [{"date":"09.07.2015","number":"22","name":"Jackson","note":"bla"}]
                 }
            }
}
```